# DataTables - server side: "No matching records found" & "filtered from NaN total entries"

Tags: datatables

Here is my client side code setting up the DataTable:

```
        var apiUrl = '/companies.php?mode=list';
        var table = $('#companiesTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                dataType: 'text',
                type: 'POST',
                url: apiUrl,
                dataSrc: function (json) {
                    return $.parseJSON(json);
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'name',
                    responsivePriority: 1,
                    width: '30%',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a href="/app/company.php?id=' + row.id + '">' + row.company_name + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'tel',
                    responsivePriority: 3,
                    width: '20%'
                },
                {
                    data: 'website',
                    responsivePriority: 4,
                    width: '15%',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<a target="_blank" href="' + row.website + '" class="trunc">' + truncate(row.website, 16) + '</a>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    orderable: false,
                    responsivePriority: 2,
                    width: '15%',
                    render: function (data, type, row) {
                        var url = '/contact.php?id=' + row.id;
                        return '<a href="' + url + '" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">View</a> '
                            <?php if ($activeUser->can('delete')) { ?>
                                + '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary delete-person" data-person="' + row.name + '" data-id="' + row.id + '">Delete</a>'
                            <?php } ?>
                                ;
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

Here is the returned JSON:

```
{
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND 1 ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0",
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": "1426",
    "recordsFiltered": "1426",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "company_name": "aaaaa",
        "tel": "00000",
        "website": "",
        "notes": "",
        "created_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "DT_RowId": "row_0",
        "DT_RowData": {
          "pkey": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "company_name": "aaaaa",
        "tel": "00000",
        "website": "",
        "notes": "",
        "created_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "DT_RowId": "row_1",
        "DT_RowData": {
          "pkey": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "company_name": "aaaaa",
        "tel": "00000",
        "website": "",
        "notes": "",
        "created_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "DT_RowId": "row_2",
        "DT_RowData": {
          "pkey": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "company_name": "aaaaa",
        "tel": "00000",
        "website": "",
        "notes": "",
        "created_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "updated_at": "2020-01-31 11:32:03",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "DT_RowId": "row_3",
        "DT_RowData": {
          "pkey": 3
        }
      }, // ..... etc, etc, etc
    ]
  }
```

And my result is: "No matching records found", and I also get: "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries (filtered from NaN total entries)" - as per this screenshot:

[image]

Can anyone explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: I thought it might be the fact that I am referencing the address data ('addr1' etc) - so I've removed this entirely, but I am still getting the same result

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this. It also has a live demo code. Inspect it and see the request and response parameter which data table adds. https://ashishontech.xyz/server-side-pagination-jquery-datatable/